# Is there any way to do login with bootstrap template when spring security is used?

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I am new to spring and thymeleaf i am having one application in which there are two Pages login and registration, but now I want to use bootstrap modals but and spring security is used in application, so anyone have idea about integrating bootstrap modal for login and registration with spring security ?

Comment: Just make the modal post to /login or whatever you have set the login page to

Comment: but how it will reopen if there is any validation error came

Comment: You'd get a response from the post, handle the response and reload whatever you want.